# Entire $f,g$ such that $f(f(z)) = p(g(z))$

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, functional-equations, complex-dynamics

Let $p(z)$ be a given polynomial of degree $3$.

How to find nonconstant entire functions $f,g$ such that $f(f(z)) = p(g(z))$ or prove they do not exist ?

---

I considered the related equation $f(f(z)) = g^2(z)$.

In particular finding nontrivial solutions , so not $C x^{2n}$.

We get $\sqrt f(f(z)) = g(z)$ , so $f(f(z))$ must have all its roots with even multiplicity.
Therefore we rewrite $f(z) = F^2(z)$ and $F(F^2(z)) = g(z)$.

We then arrive at $F^2(z) = F^{-1}(g(z))$ so $g(z) = F(G(z)) = \sqrt f(G(z))$.

Then $f(f(z)) = f(G(z))$. I got confused after this , so instead of continuing this approach I switched to using derivatives :

$D f(f(z)) = D g^2(z)$.

$f'(f(z)) f'(z) = 2 g(z) g'(z)$

From here on I tried to consider arguments like " if $f'(z)$ divides $g'(z)$ " and the alike , but without succes.

I have the impression Im close to a solution here.

---

edit : As Thomas Andrews point out there is a trivial solution : $f(z)=g(z)=p(z)$.
But of course one wonders about the existance of others.

Comment: What about $f(z)=g(z)=p(z)$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes that works.

Comment: There are more trivial solutions, for example $g(z)=p^{2n-1}(z)$ and $f(z)=p^n(z)$ (where $p^k$ is repeated composition.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any entire function $h$, you can define $f(z)=p(h(z))$ and $g(z)=h(p(h(z)))$ then $f\circ f = (p\circ h)\circ(p\circ h) = p\circ(h\circ p\circ h) = p\circ g$.

That's a general trick that will work for finding solutions to $f\circ f = p\circ g$ in any semigroup (an algebra with one associative binary operation.)

Not sure if there are any other solutions in the specific case of the algebra of entire functions.

Comment: Still wondering about the other solutions ...